# R Working with very wide image data data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm having a project where I look at images and have to identify some unique id's given a image

I've however run into a problem.

As seen below I have my main code Snippet. Additionally I have 2 other files which handles the loading of images/libraries and the handling of path variables (since we are 3 people working on the project)

When I load in the data and have converted it to the desired form as an data.frame where each image is a single row of data. The data.frame simply refuses to operate with a lot of the operations permitted in R.

I tried to make it print out a large piece of its context of the first row.

The data frame size:

- Rows: N (The amount of Images)
- Cols: 375002 (The last 2 is the name of the image and the id associated)

It worked for me to write out every column with 20 rows. but other operations failed and left R and R Studio hanging forever needing the "kill -9" in order to stop them.

My specs:

- OS: Linux ( Ubuntu 14.04 ) 64-bit
- R: Version 3.2.2
- GCC: Version 4.8.4
- RAM: 32 GB
- CPU: I7 Laptop
- Disk: SSD 250 GB

  ```
  # Load labels from a specified file
  labels <- loadLabels(path = LABEL_FILENAME)

  # Fetch 2 whale id's
  randomWhaleId <- sample(unique(labels[, 2]), size = 2, replace = FALSE)
  # Fetch the file ~ id's 
  whaleImages <- labels[which(labels[, 2] %in% randomWhaleId), ]

  # Import image into R
  images <- loadImagesByName(path = IMG_PATH_RESIZED, imagefiles = whaleImages[, 1])

  # transform image into grayscale
  df_grays <- lapply(images, function(x) channel(x, "gray"))
  # extract data frames from the image object and convert to list (2d -> 1d)
  df_grays <- lapply(df_grays, function(x) as.list(imageData(x)));
  # Convert list to data frame
  df_grays <- data.frame(rbindlist(df_grays))
  # adding info columns
  df_grays <- cbind(df_grays, whaleImages)

  # Runs perfectly fine
  for(i in 1:ncol(df_grays)) {
    print(i)
    print(df_grays[,i])
  }

  # Runs forever 
  write.csv(x = df_grays, file = "/tmp/images.csv")

  # Start H2O server
  localH2O = h2o.init(nthreads = 6)
  # send to h2o (didn't work either)
  df_grays_h2o <- as.h2o(localH2O, df_grays)
  ```

Comment: Can you please enrich your code snippet since some important background is missing: Where do "loadLabels" and "loadImagesByName" come from (R package -> library function), How many image files do you process at once and how big are they together (MBs)...

Comment: @RYoda raises good points for getting help specifically. I have a more general suggestion ... 370k columns is pretty hairy. Have you considered/tried transposing it or melting it to facilitate a more "typical" tabular structure i.e. longer than it is wide

Comment: Ah yea this issue has been hanging, sorry. But my conclusion was to implement it in java which was able to write these images to csv in matter of very few seconds, so it seem that r has problem with large character arrays(strings), and that was why it was so slow that it took forever.